# Django custom settings for app

Tags: python, django

I am currently developing an app for django that needs to have some custom settings that can be changed at runtime by admin users, and those settings have to be accessible to another separate system that uses the same database.

On one hand, we could store those settings in a json file and have it accessible to both systems, as only the django system will actually make any changes to the settings. On the other hand, we could just store those settings as a lone row in on a 'settings' table on the database.

The first choice seems quite cumbersome to deal with, and might result in some problems of multiple accesses, while the other would need a whole table in the database for a single row.

Is any of these ideas any good, or is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: Could you have a generic 'settings' table? Then you wouldn't need a table per entry - you'd just have a basic key-value store instead.

Comment: That's actually what I wanted to mean with "lone entry", sorry, will edit. What I'm wondering really is if there's any kind of drawback to having a table with just one row or if that's a perfectly fine idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a table. Remember, Django makes it **really easy**. Just create another class for the settings table and populate it. You should be able to access it with just about any other language/system - e.g., PHP. The data gets backed up with everything else in the database, if you move to a different server the data moves along with everything else, etc. Yes, the overhead is technically a little more than a plain text file, but if it is really that small then that overhead is insignificant. If the list of settings grows over time then having it in a searchable database will make updates & retrieval much easier that a text file.